In a simple series circuit, one with a diode, if I were to calculate the current via KVL, then that current MUST satisfy the diode equation?
In a simple series circuit, one with a diode (given its voltage), if I were to calculate the current via KVL, then that current MUST satisfy the diode equation as well? Were that the case, then I should be able to calculate the current just by solving the diode equation without even having to fuss with KVL, right?

How do you calculate the current using KVL without knowledge of the voltage across the diode?

Given the voltage across the diode

In such a case, a graphical solution is necessary using the e-function for the diode.

The graphical solution gives the whole point, i.e., the voltage across the diode AND the current. My question is, If the voltage across the diode is known to begin with, then even without KVL, one should be able to calc the current via the diode eqation and If one calc the current with KLV, then it should satisfy the diode equation right?

@Jack The Shockley diode equation says $I_\text{D}=I_\text{SAT}\cdot\left[\exp\left(\frac{V_\text{D}}{\eta,\cdot,V_T}\right)-1\right]$. $V_T\approx 26:\text{mV}$ and $\eta\ge 1$. So yes, you can calculate the current. This is still an ideal case, though. There is bulk resistance. There are at least three regions of operation for the currents which have different factors (one for the low current case with surface recombination effects taking over, one for the high current case with current crowding taking over, and the usual case in between those.)

@periblepsis and it MUST satisfy the KVL as well right?

@Jack Yes. Of course. So if you place a resistor in series with the diode or if you take into account the internal bulk resistance of the diode, which the above equation does not do, then the result becomes more complex. In that case, you need to solve a different equation for $I_\text{D}$, which will require the use of the LambertW (branch 0.) This gets into some math. But technically KVL still applies. It's just that the math has gone "non-linear" on you.


If the voltage across the diode is known to begin with,

Then you know the current through the diode. The device physics of a diode imply a specific current as a consequence of the voltage across it, and the exponential diode equation (or a more thorough/exact equation) describes those device physics.

then even without KVL, one should be able to calc the current via the diode eqation [sic]

Yes. KVL allows you to relate the diode voltage to other voltages in your overall circuit

and If one calc the current with KLV [sic], then it should satisfy the diode equation right?

KVL alone cannot give you a current. It can relate voltages to each other, and then you have other means (branch equations, KCL, etc) to obtain currents.

Were that the case, then I should be able to calculate the current just by solving the diode equation without even having to fuss with KVL, right?

If you consider only KVL, you typically end up with an underdetermined system of equations. KCL, KVL, and branch consitutent equations must all be true in a solved circuit.
If you then used KCL, KVL, and branch constituent equations to solve a consistent/solvable circuit, then the diode equation is one of the equations in the system, and hence must be satisfied by any solution.
The diode equation isn't particularly special here. You could take a resistor, write its branch constituent equation (i.e. Ohm's Law, \$V = IR\$), and do the same analysis - Ohm's Law alone lets you relate resistor voltage to resistor current, KCL and KVL let you relate this current and voltage to other currents and voltages. Structurally, this is the same - just with a linear equation that may be more familiar.

And there can't be a solution that isn't a solution to the diode equation as well. In other words, the solution is always the operating point, right?

@Jack Yes, exactly. And if you skip the diode equation (or any other branch constituent equation, or pretty much any of the equations, for that matter) when setting up the system of equations, you're very likely going to end up with an underdefined system of equations with more unknowns than equations.

RE "KVL cannot give you a current.", it can. You just need to write the voltages of each component (or branch) as a function of the current. In fact solving the KVL equations for the currents is exactly how we use it in mesh analysis.

@ThePhoton That's a reflection of the overall system rather than KVL itself; in that sense every equation gives you currents and voltages simply because the system is underconstrained without each and every one of them there - I'll rephrase to make this more clear.


if I were to calculate the current via KVL, then that current MUST satisfy the diode equation as well?

Yes. For example you can use the mesh method of circuit analysis. That basically means making a KVL equation (with mesh currents as the unknown variables) for all the independent loops in the circuit, and solving them to obtain the mesh currents. From the mesh currents and the constitutive relations for each element you can then find the voltages across all the elements.
This result will be consistent with the I-V equations (constitutive relations) for all the components in the circuit.

Were that the case, then I should be able to calculate the current just by solving the diode equation without even having to fuss with KVL, right?

No, because you need KVL (or some other equations like KCL that capture the interconnections of the circuit) to know how the voltage of the diode balances with the voltages of all the other components in the circuit to give the voltage across the diode.
Even if your circuit is just a voltage source and a diode in a loop, it's KVL that tells you that the voltage across the diode is equal to the voltage produced by the voltage source. You might have enough experience to just see that it's "obvious" this is true, but it's actually KVL that makes it true, so when you use this fact you aren't ignoring KVL.

I didn't mean ignoring KVL but just having the freedom to not work with in order to determine the current.

Assuming that it is stated earlier the voltage across the diode in the meant circuit.

@Jack, if you already know the voltage across the diode then you're not "analyzing the circuit". That's already been done to determine the voltage across the diode, so you don't need to do it again. The rest of the circuit is irrelevant at that point and you're just making a calculation from the diode equation.
